# Water Damaged Nintendo 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

A few months ago, I had an original small Nintendo 3DS. One evening, I had it with me. I was wearing a large heavy coat, so I did not notice it in the pocket. Later that evening, I threw my coat in the wash, not knowing it was there. The wash was 6 minutes in and the  thing had already been soaked. I immediately removed everything from it (including the battery and SD card) and placed it in dry rice for 4 days, emptying and refilling the rice every day.

The system will not power on. When charging, however, the orange light turns on. I have removed the battery and inserted it into a different model and it shows to be full and working just fine. The only way to investigate it further is to open up the whole thing and take the motherboard out. I do not want to do that because I have no skill in opening up technology and ave a bad history of reassembling things wrong or out of place (and I have no electronic repair equipment or anything that can help except for a screwdriver. I have a lot of games inside of the SD card and it's the only way for me to transfer them to my newer console without spending at least $100.

What can I do? What should I do? Is there any hope for me? I would really like to know what I am able to do. This could save me a lot of money, too.

I hope something can be done and I appreciate all answers. Thank you!

Comment: (NOTE) I have made a similar question regarding the same situation. However, that one was about transferring games. This question is about the actual physical repair of the system. (I cannot take it to Nintendo.)

Comment: Depending on the washing machine, there could have been soap in the mix, etc. etc. The board could have rusted somewhere, maybe the battery connection ports are fried, there's any number of possibilities.

Comment: Dry it in sunlight. keep it for a month **before powering it ON**

Answer (score 1):

[www.ifixit.com](http://www.ifixit.com) might help you. They have teardowns and guides for repair. For example, here is the [3DS Teardown guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nintendo+3DS+Teardown/5029)

If it's really dead, nintendo has a black friday deal (new 3ds for $99)

Comment: I already have a newer model. Even if I had gotten another newer model, it would be of no help to me, for it uses microSD cards, not regular SD cards like my old one does. However, I really appreciate your response and will look to the website and see what I can do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there's no way to know what exactly happened unless you open it up. Then based on what you see, you can determine which guides you can use.